# TCP close 2-way handshake with wirshark package

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, handshake

I got a pcap package use tcpdump command. In this pcap, the TCP close in 2-way handshake!

[image: tcp close 2-way handshake]

Questions:

1. In this picture, can anyone determine who initiated the signal to close the connection?
2. why TCP close in 2-way handshake? it does not make sense!

Comment: I would ask this question there: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireshark

Comment: thanks, i will try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a half-close, initiated by the side that sent the FIN. A full close would require a FIN in the other direction, and a corresponding ACK.